# Conceptual question about iOS object/method delegation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, delegates

I have view controller A, table view controller B and view controller C. In A's viewDidLoad method I add B as a subview of A. When an outlet in A is tapped then C is presented as a modal view. When an outlet is tapped in C; I need to call some method in B. How can I set B as C's delegate if there is no direct relationship between the two? Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need to rethink your design. If "there is no direct relationship between B and C", then C should not be calling methods on B. If C *does* need to call methods on B, then there *is* a relationship.

That said, since your view controller A knows about both of these objects, it can act as the link between them. You can have C call a method on A, which will then call a method on B. Of course, this requires C to have a reference to A; since you say that C is presented when a button is tapped in A, C has such a reference through its `parentViewController` property. For example:

```
// In C
- (IBAction) buttonPressed {
    [self.parentViewController passMessageToB:self];
}

// In A
- (void) passMessageToB: (id)sender {
    // sender is a reference to C, so B will be able to
    // pass information back if needed
    [B actOnMessageFromC:sender];
}

// In B
- (void) actOnMessageFromC: (id)sender {
    // Do whatever is needed
}
```

It's possible to make this even more complex -- you could even pass a particular selector to A that it could call on B, but at that point I think you would *definitely* need to reconsider your design and the connections between B and C.

Answer (score 1):

As you written , you could access both (**B & C**) in a common class i.e. **A** so. It's very easy to set **B** as delegate for **C**.

[The Basics of Protocols and Delegates.](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follow.

```
@interface C : UIViewController
{
    id parent;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) id parent;

@implementation C
-(IBAction)methodInC:(id)sender
{
    [parent methodName]; //B is parent so this will call method declared in B.
}
@end
```

Now while presenting B from C controller, allocate the object and set parent as

```
objB.parent = self;
```

This way you can easily call methods declared in B.

Hope it helps.